# does the accurancy of this algorithm converge to 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, modular-arithmetic

I have an algorithm that solves a certain problem.
It's not important for now what it really does, but I will sketch it for my problem.
I have a problem input $k$ (natural number) which can be solved algorithmically by a certain prime $p_k$.
Then it automatically solves every number in the residue class $[k]\pmod {m}$
where $m$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $p_k$.
Now I could iterate this for numbers $k$, save the $p_k$ and hope, that every natural number $k$ is solves once.
Here is an example:
Suppose that the numbers
$$
[1]_4, [3]_4
$$
can already be solved by any primes.
That means I can solve $\frac{1}{2}$ of all cases.
Let this be called the accurancy.
Now suppose there is another prime $p$ which solves the $0$.
If it would be
$
\operatorname{ord}_p(2) = 4,
$
then I could solve the numbers
$$
[0]_4, [1]_4, [3]_4
$$
and so $\frac{3}{4}$

But if it was
$
\operatorname{ord}_p(2) = 8,
$
then I could solve the numbers
$
[0]_8, [1]_8, [3]_8, [5]_8, [7]_8.
$
It's now only $\frac{5}{8}$ that I solve, but still more than $\frac{1}{2}$.

So, every time that I solve a new case, no matter what the order of the prime is, the accurancy becomes more.

But my question is: does it converge to 1?

Comment: Is it accurate to rephrase your question as follows? Let $S_1=\emptyset$, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$, pick an integer $x\notin S_n$ and a modulus $m$ (which is the order of $2$ mod some prime) and let $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup(x+m\Bbb Z).$ Then does the natural density of $S_n$ in $\Bbb Z$ approach $1$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Karl Yes. But I guess I could my answer my question. Let's say I have infinitely many primes in my set $S$. Suppose they are ordered by $\operatorname{ord}_p(2).$ If $\operatorname{ord}_{p_{n+1}}(2)>3\operatorname{ord}_{p_{n}}(2)$ for all $n$, my accurancy will tend to $\frac{2}{3}$